# c# implementing timeout to read complete tcp packet by server

Tags: c#, client

In the tcp header packet their is a field which mentions the total size of packet. I have implemented my server which is listening to multiple client in following way

```
int numberOfClientsYouNeedToConnect = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfClientsYouNeedToConnect; i++)
        {
            Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listeners));
            newThread.Start();
        }

public static void Listeners()
    {
        try
        {
            Socket socketForClient = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();

            if (socketForClient.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client : " + socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint + " is now connected to server.");
                NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(socketForClient);
                //networkStream.ReadTimeout = 30;
                System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(networkStream);
                System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(networkStream);

                while (true)
                {
                    string theString = streamReader.ReadLine();
                    //Console.WriteLine(theString);
                    byte[] input_stream = extra_function.ConvertHexToString(theString);
                    for (int i = 0; i < input_stream.Length; i++)
                    {
                       // Console.WriteLine("hi");
                        Console.Write(input_stream[i]);
                    }


                    if (theString != "exit")
                    {
                        // original message from client
                        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("Message recieved from client(" + socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint + ") : " + theString);

                        // ASCII code for the message from client 
                        Console.Write("ASCII Code for message is : ");
                        foreach (char c in theString)
                        {
                            Console.Write(System.Convert.ToInt32(c) + " ");
                        }
                    }
                 }
```

But my problem is that server without receiving complete packet it starts processing it while other part of packet comes little later. So how can I change my code so that server receives complete packet and then process it. The size of the total packet is included in the header of packet. The server should wait till it receive  that much bytes from client or wait till some time for getting complete packet.

Comment: You use StreamReader and StreamWriter, so your protocol seems to be *text based*. Therefore your *packet* is *one line*.

Comment: ok actually protocol is not text based but it will be sending and receiving tcp packets.

Comment: You can not use StreamReader and StreamWriter for binary data. Use networkStream directly.

Comment: ok how can I use networkStream to receive complete packet and then process it.

Comment: First read a few bytes defining the length of the packet, then loop till you get the rest,

Comment: ok How can I specify time period to wait for receiving packet or else discard it completely if timeout occurs.

Comment: How about reading some docs about TCP & .Net

Answer (score -1):

Did you try `StreamReader.ReadToEnd()` instead of `StreamReader.ReadLine()` ?

Comment: Server wouldn't get any *message* until client closes the connection.